# google geocoding and haversine distance calculation in R

Tags: r, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using the `geocode` function from the `ggmap` package to geocode country names and then passing them onto the `distHaversine` in the `geosphere` library to calculate the distance between two countries.

Sample of my data is as follows:

```
              Country.Value                   Address.Country

 1:           United States                   United States 
 2:                  Cyprus                   United States 
 3:               Indonesia                   United States 
 4:                Tanzania                        Tanzania 
 5:              Madagascar                   United States 
 6:                  Belize                          Canada 
 7:               Argentina                       Argentina 
 8:                   Egypt                           Egypt 
 9:            South Africa                    South Africa 
10:                Paraguay                        Paraguay
```

I have also used if-else statements to try and stay within the geocoding limits set by the free *Google Maps geocoder*. My code is as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row<-df.cont.long[i,]

  src_lon<- 0.0
  src_lat<- 0.0
  trgt_lon<- 0.0
  trgt_lat<- 0.0  


  if((row$Country.Value=='United States')){  #Reduce geocoding requirements
    trgt_lon<- -95.7129
    trgt_lat<- 37.0902
  }
  else if((row$Address.Country=='United States')){  #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    src_lon<- -95.7129
    src_lat<- 37.0902
  }
  else if((row$Country.Value=='Canada')){  #Reduce geocoding requirements
    trgt_lon<- -106.3468
    trgt_lat<- 56.1304
  }
  else if((row$Primary.Address.Country=='Canada')){  #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    src_lon<- -106.3468
    src_lat<- 56.1304
  }
  else if(row$Country.Value == row$Address.Country){   #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    # trgt<-geocode(row$Country.Value)
    # trgt_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    # trgt_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)
    # src_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    # src_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)
  }
  else{
    trgt<-geocode(row$Country.Value, output=c("latlon"))
    trgt_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    trgt_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)

    src<-geocode(row$Address.Country)
    src_lon<-as.numeric(src$lon)
    src_lat<-as.numeric(src$lat)

  }

  print(i)
  print(c(row$Address.Country, src_lon, src_lat))
  print(c(row$Country.Value, trgt_lon, trgt_lat))

  print(distHaversine( p1=c(as.numeric(src$lon), as.numeric(src$lat)), p2=c(as.numeric(trgt$lon), as.numeric(trgt$lat)) ))


}
```

In the output

1. Sometimes geocoding is done, sometimes not, and is defaulting to 0.0
2. Sometimes distance is getting calculated, sometimes not

I have no idea where the code is going wrong.

Moreover, uncommenting the lines where I check if the *Country.Value* and *Address.Country* are equal, makes things even worse.

Answer (score 2):

The functions you're using are vectorized, so all you really need is

```
library(ggmap)
library(geosphere)

distHaversine(geocode(as.character(df$Country.Value)), 
              geocode(as.character(df$Address.Country)))
# [1]        0 10432624 14978567        0 15868544  4588708        0        0        0        0
```

Note the `as.character`s are there because `ggmap::geocode` doesn't like factors. The results make sense:

```
df$distance <- distHaversine(geocode(as.character(df$Country.Value), source = 'dsk'), 
                             geocode(as.character(df$Address.Country), source = 'dsk'))

df
#    Country.Value Address.Country distance
# 1  United States   United States        0
# 2         Cyprus   United States 10340427
# 3      Indonesia   United States 14574480
# 4       Tanzania        Tanzania        0
# 5     Madagascar   United States 16085178
# 6         Belize          Canada  5172279
# 7      Argentina       Argentina        0
# 8          Egypt           Egypt        0
# 9   South Africa    South Africa        0
# 10      Paraguay        Paraguay        0
```

---

#### Edit

If you don't want to use `ggmap::geocode`, `tmap::geocode_OSM` is another geocoding function that uses OpenStreetMap data. However, because it is not vectorized, you need to iterate over it columnwise:

```
distHaversine(t(sapply(df$Country.Value, function(x){tmap::geocode_OSM(x)$coords})), 
              t(sapply(df$Address.Country, function(x){tmap::geocode_OSM(x)$coords})))
# [1]        0 10448111 14794618        0 16110917  5156823        0        0        0        0
```

or rowwise:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x){distHaversine(tmap::geocode_OSM(x['Country.Value'])$coords, 
                                       tmap::geocode_OSM(x['Address.Country'])$coords)})
# [1]        0 10448111 14794618        0 16110917  5156823        0        0        0        0
```

and subset to the `coords` data. Also note that Google, DSK, and OSM all choose different centers for each country, so the resulting distances are differ by some distance.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate if-else statements in the vectorized solution? Otherwise, I will go over the 2500 limit of google maps geocoder.

Comment: Use `source = 'dsk'`, and you don't have to worry. It auto-caches with DSK, too, I believe. Alternately, you can calculate your own centroids from map data, if you like.

Comment: Even after adding `source='dsk'`. I am getting _Error: google restricts requests to 2500 requests a day for non-business use._ as soon as I run the code

Comment: Odd, but it does have an `override_limit` parameter that might fix your problem. There are also other geocoding functions/services, e.g. `tmap::geocode_OSM`, which uses OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: tmap seems to be a better solution. I am using the following code: `df$dist<-distHaversine(geocode_OSM(as.character(df$Country.Value), projection = "longlat")$coords, geocode_OSM(as.character(df$Address.Country), projection = "longlat")$coords)` But the distances are being calculated as 0! But when I try a simplified version `distHaversine(geocode_OSM("Peru", projection = "longlat")$coords, geocode_OSM("United States", projection = "longlat")$coords)`, it works!

Comment: `tmap::geocode_OSM` is not vectorized and gives you results in a different format, so you need to loop it and rearrange: `distHaversine(t(sapply(df$Country.Value, function(x){tmap::geocode_OSM(x)$coords})), t(sapply(df$Address.Country, function(x){tmap::geocode_OSM(x)$coords})))` or loop rowwise: `apply(df, 1, function(x){distHaversine(tmap::geocode_OSM(x[1])$coords, tmap::geocode_OSM(x[2])$coords)})`

Comment: thanks `alistaire`. If you add the last one as an answer, I will accept it.